# rewrite htaccess apache to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

How to convert this rewrite code:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|sitemap.xml|google(.+)\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is from Stikked script https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked/blob/master/htdocs/.htaccess

I try to reproduce it in nginx format, but get error that variable `$1` is unknow

```
if ($1 !~ "^(index.php|static|favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|google(.+).html)"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^(index.php|static|favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|google(.+).html)"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!     very much